# Spring data, hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, entity, spring-data

Имеется сущность Ride :

```
public class Ride extends BaseEntity {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @Setter
  @Getter
  private Schedule schedule;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @Setter
  @Getter
  private Station stationFrom;
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @Setter
  @Getter
  private Station stationTo;
  @Column
  @Setter
  @Getter
  private Double price;

  public Ride() {
  }

  @Builder
  public Ride(Integer id, Schedule schedule, Station stationFrom,
      Station stationTo, Double price) {
    super(id);
    this.schedule = schedule;
    this.stationFrom = stationFrom;
    this.stationTo = stationTo;
    this.price = price;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + "schedule=" + schedule +
        ", stationFrom=" + stationFrom +
        ", stationTo=" + stationTo;
  }
}
```

Необходимо сделать update только некоторых полей , т.е. которые нужно выставляю значения , которые хочу оставить без изменений - null, после update ,на данный момент,  все которые были null , установились в БД в null .

Comment: как вы делаете update?

Comment: @Repository
public interface RideRepository extends JpaRepository<Ride, Integer> {}    Вызываю метод save у репозитория

Comment: анотации Getter/ Setter за классом выставляйте. Код сократится

Comment: выберите тот тип каскада, который вам нужен

Answer (score 0):

Пометьте класс сущности аннотацией [@DynamicUpdate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/DynamicUpdate.html)

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
public class Ride {
    ...
}
```

Только учтите, что это может привести не к ожидаемому росту производительности, а наоборот её падению. В обычной ситуации Hibernate анализируют структуру класса один раз, при загрузке, генерирует SQL-запрос для обновления, кэширует его и потом использует каждый раз при обновлении. С включенным динамическим обновлением ему придётся выполнять эту процедуру при каждом обновлении сущности.

Comment: Не помогло , все поля которые null , в бд выставляются в null

Comment: Ну естественно. А зачем вы их в null ставите? Просто не изменяйте их.